# Generic approach of mirroring data from Oracle to another database

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, plsql

We have source Oracle database, where we have a lot of tabels (let say 100) which we need to mirror to target database. So we need to copy data increments periodically to another db tables. The target database is currently Oracle, but in the short future it will be probably changed to a different database technology.

So currently we can create a PL/SQL procedure which will  dynamically generate DML (insert, update or merge statements) for each table (assuming that the source and target table have exactly the same attributes) from Oracle metadata.
But we would rather create some db technology independent solution so when we change target database to another (e.g. MS SQL or Postgres), then we will no need to change whole logic of data mirroring.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to do it differently (preferably in java)?

Thanks for every advice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is called CDC - continuous data capture. In case of Oracle this is complicated because Oracle is usually asking money for this.
So you can use:

- PL/SQL or Java and use SQL to incrementally detect changes in data. IT requires plenty of work and performance is bad.
- Use tools based on Oracle triggers, which will dects data changes and pushes them into some queue.
- Use tool which can parse content of Oracle Archive logs. These are commercial products: GoldenGate (from Oracle) and Shareplex (Dell/EMC/dunno). GoldenDate also contains Java technology(XStreams) which allows you to inject Java visitor into the data stream. Those technologies also support sending data changes into Kafka stream.
- There are plenty of tools like Debezium, Informatica, Tibco which can not parse Archived logs by themself, but rather they use Oracle's internal tool LogMiner. These tools usually do not scale well and can not cope with higher data volumes.

[Here is quite article in as a summary.](https://rmoff.net/2018/12/12/streaming-data-from-oracle-into-kafka/) If you have money pick GoldenGate or Shareplex. If you don't pick Debezium or any other Java CDC project based on Logminer.